# Wifi device suddenly vanished on ASUS TUF laptop

Tags: networking, wireless, 19.04

I have an Asus TUF565GE-BQ165T running Ubuntu 19.04 since june and every thing was (almost) fine until today when the wifi interface suddenly vanished while I was working. Wired connection works fine. I remember I already had a similar (not sure it was the same) issue and I found a one line solution here but stupidly I didn't think to write it down. As I'm not a low level expert, I'm a bit lost...

**No wlan device**

```
maurycy@kali> ifconfig 
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.8.163  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.8.255
        inet6 fe80::cf64:51d7:2ad3:5fd5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:9d:92:44:9a:14  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25646  bytes 13884481 (13.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22360  bytes 3319809 (3.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 5559  bytes 568700 (568.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5559  bytes 568700 (568.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:a9:7c:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
maurycy@kali> sudo iwconfig 
virbr0    no wireless extensions.
enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.
```

What I've checked so far:

**Hardware check**: 
It looks like the hardware is detected:

```
maurycy@kali> sudo  lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       produit: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 14.3
       information bus: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 10
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       ressources: irq:16 mémoire:a441c000-a441ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nom logique: enp3s0
       version: 15
       numéro de série: 0c:9d:92:44:9a:14
       taille: 1Gbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.8.163 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       ressources: irq:16 portE/S:3000(taille=256) mémoire:a4204000-a4204fff mémoire:a4200000-a4203fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       identifiant matériel: 2
       nom logique: virbr0
       numéro de série: 52:54:00:a9:7c:5b
       fonctionnalités: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DÉSACTIVÉ
       description: Ethernet interface
       identifiant matériel: 3
       nom logique: virbr0-nic
       numéro de série: 52:54:00:a9:7c:5b
       taille: 10Mbit/s
       fonctionnalités: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

**Module check**: looks like modules are here

```
maurycy@kali> sudo lsmod | grep wifi
iwlwifi               315392  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              688128  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

**`rfkill`** doesn't help

```
aurycy@kali> sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
/home/maurycy/tmp
maurycy@kali> sudo     rfkill unblock wlan
/home/maurycy/tmp
maurycy@kali> sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

**EDIT** as per **chili555** comment request. Lines 5 and 6 doesn't look to smell good, right ?

```
maurycy@kali> dmesg | grep iwl
[    5.630611] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.647395] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.697280] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x318
[    5.739122] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    5.739126] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    5.739157] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x23f5
[    5.739158] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    5.739160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    7.126215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[ 1168.661742]  iwlmvm snd_seq snd_seq_device aesni_intel mac80211 ecdh_generic media snd_timer input_leds aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd iwlwifi glue_helper asus_nb_wmi snd asus_wmi intel_cstate idma64 mei_me intel_rapl_perf serio_raw sparse_keymap soundcore cfg80211 wmi_bmof mxm_wmi hid_multitouch 8250_dw mei virt_dma processor_thermal_device intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid asus_wireless acpi_pad nvidia_uvm(OE) sch_fq_codel vhost_net vhost tap parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear usbhid hid_generic nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) i915 kvmgt vfio_mdev mdev vfio_iommu_type1 vfio kvm irqbypass i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt nvme fb_sys_fops r8169 drm ahci realtek ipmi_devintf i2c_i801 intel_lpss_pci
```

**Edit 2**: Problem solved without a real solution...

Actually, the laptop is in dual boot, so I tested with windows and wifi worked without problem. Rebooting on Linux "solved" the problem as I got the wifi device and the network back. Yet I don't consider that as a real solution...

The boot logs show the following:

```
maurycy@kali> dmesg | grep iwl
[    5.581765] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.597993] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.651909] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x318
[    5.701002] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 38:ba:f8:80:89:00
[    5.786983] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.793856] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    7.032018] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM =disabled)
[    7.035050] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu, or Kali?

Comment: @heynnema: `kali`  is the name of my laptop, but it's running Ubuntu 19.04